# Does IE9 support expandable popups using JQuery? Does IE9 handle this kind of script differently than Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a web app slide presentation that has popups. The popups don't appear in IE9 and I'm trying to figure out if it is a compatibility issue or if there is an alternate way to code the fading in and out of popups so that it works properly in IE9. Any help? Here are the relevant bits of code:

Html:

```
<div id="bottom_btn_container_2btns" style="text-align:left"> 
  <a class="bottom_btn js-expandable" data-popup="popup-1">STUDY DESCRIPTION</a> <br/>
  <a href="linkEliq_irgo_1_3_1.html"class="bottom_btn">ADDITIONAL STUDIES</a> 
  <!--<a class="bottom_btn js-expandable" data-popup="popup-2" >ADDITIONAL STUDIES</a>-->       
</div>
```

And the HTML Popup:

```
<div class="popup" id="popup-1">
<div class="popup-inner" style="height:490px; width:820px;margin-left:120px">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <div class="tac">
      <header>
        <h4 style="margin-bottom:5px;">Study Description<sup>1</sup></h4>
      </header>
      <article> //and then the content starts
```

Relevant JS:

```
  var initExpandables = function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.js-expandable', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var expandableElem = $(this),
            popupId = expandableElem.data('popup');

        $('#' + popupId).addClass('popup-opened');
    });
};
```

I'm having a hard time finding if there are conflicts between IE9 and the JS/Jquery. I thought perhaps the CSS might be the problem but it seems to work fine in Chrome and FF. Here's the relevant CSS just in case:

```
#bottom_btn_container_2btns {
position: absolute;
float: right;
left: 768px;
bottom: 100px;
z-index: 8000;
height: 85px;
width: auto;
text-align:right;
margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

CSS for .popup and .popup-opened:

```
.popup {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 9700;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
}   

.popup-opened {
pointer-events: all;
opacity: 1;
}
```

If it's IE9 that is the problem then is there an alternate way of getting popups to expand that is compatible with IE9? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the CSS for `.popup` and `.popup-opened`, or better yet, make a fiddle.

Comment: And please use different terminology.  A pop-up is a new browser window that opens.  What you are doing is more of a lightbox.

Comment: I suspect the problem is here: `popupId = expandableElem.data('popup');` - have you tried `popupId = expandableElem.attr('data-popup');` ?

Comment: Sorry, cale_b. The code was written by someone else and since I'm fairly new to the professional web development world, I didn't know the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try and it didn't seem to make a difference. The buttons still remain nonfunctional.

Comment: Do lightboxes work in IE9? Or is there a smoother alternative way of writing this code out?

Comment: `"Do lightboxes work in IE9?"` Really? IE9 isn't *that* bad.